# Can't bind angular-mentions in contenteditable in angular 8

Tags: angular, jhipster, angular8, contenteditable

I am using **contenteditable** in the div element in an **Angular 8 project**. I tried using **angular-mentions** in my project. I have used npm to include that mention in my project. While doing that **[mention] tag** is not at all recognized.

I am using this https://github.com/dmacfarlane/angular-mentions

```
npm install angular-mentions
```

Here is the error I am getting in the console:

> Can't bind to 'mention' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ][mention]="items" id="rteditor" class="scrollbox-content"
>   contenteditable="true" placeholder="Type a "):

Here is the div element where I am using the mention

```
<div [mention]="items" id="rteditor" class="scrollbox-content" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Type a message here..."></div>
```

This is the angular mention version I am using:

```
"angular-mentions": "^1.1.2",
```

I also have imported the module in the **app.module.ts** before using it in my component:

```
@NgModule({ imports: [ BrowserModule, MentionModule]})
```

I have followed the below demo and implemented the same, still it didn't work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mentions?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

**Note:**

I have also tried with the latest version (1.1.3) of angular-mention. Still the issue persists.

I have removed the angular-mention package completely and installed it again.

I have Googled and tried various ways to fix this issue, but ended up with no solution.

Could anyone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added your dependency to src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts as explained in your project's README.md?

Comment: Works out of the box for me. I just did `npm i angular-mentions`, imported the module and it works with a `contenteditable` div. I'm not sure what your problem might be, give us more info please (JH version, full code sample, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**


Changed the angular-mentions import statement as below. It worked!

```
import { MentionModule } from 'angular-mentions/';
```